# Possible to highlight matching quotes in vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

With the syntax highlighting in vim, I get the handy feature where the matching paren or bracket will be highlighted when I put the cursor over it. Is it possible to do the same thing for quotes?

Answer (score 6):

While not eloquent, one workaround is to select everything inside of matching quotes.  You can do this by using the command:

```
vi"
```

This will select everything in-between the quotes.  However, you won't get proper results with nested quotes as it will match the first found ".

Comment: I'm a big fan of this, it seems to work also with other characters if you replace the " with what you want to be inside. I'm not sure I understand what's going on though, could someone explain that? v is select and i is insert, so where does this behavior come from?

Comment: @AlexLi :help +textobjects  Text Objects in vim are cool.  This is a good article on them  https://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/

Answer (score 4):

The problem with quotes is that they are symmetrical.  It would be very hard to determine which quotes belong with each other.

For instance: `"Which \"quotes\" go with each other in this statement?"`

This has been discussed on the vim mailing lists a few times, as well as in the bug trackers of a few of the auto-delimiter type plugins.  In every case that *I've seen*, it's been decided that this is better left as is.

Comment: Vim's quote text-objects (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#aquote) already have the smarts to deal with that.  The problem is that `searchpairpos()`, which is what the MatchParen plugin uses to highlight parens, isn't able to find matching quotes.

Comment: Clearly the vim folks have figured this out well enough to highlight the quoted text properly, so I can't see why it would be any harder to highlight the quote itself when the cursor is over it. And, wouldn't brackets have the same issue? E.g. `{Which \{bracket\} matches the first bracket?}`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854888/6688314) in matchquote except it has the unfortunate limitation that *only the current line is considered*.
[matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) seems to comes close by allowing defining of multi-line matches of words such as if/endif but still no multi-line possibility that I can figure out to get matching for " and '.

Comment: I appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

VIM already highlights quoted text in a different color, so you can easily identify strings. Do you really need it to match quotes when the whole string is already highlighted?

Comment: "Need"? no. "Would like"? yes.

Comment: Fair enough, but I was trying to get at: "Why would you want to match quotes when vim already highlights the whole string for you". Can you give us a use case?

Comment: It would convenient to be able to use the % command on a quote. (jump to matching parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

From :h matchparen

> The characters to be matched come from the 'matchpairs' option.  You
> can change the value to highlight different matches.  Note that not
> everything is possible.  For example, you can't highlight single or
> double quotes, because the start and end are equal.